# Openshift Virtualization create image from snapshot

Tags: openshift

I have taken snapshot of a virtual machine in Openshift.I want to create a new Image of that snapshot in qcow2 format. Is that possible. i tried #qemu-img create -f /path/to/xml.file of the snapshot. But it did not allow because it was looking for file not in xml format.

Comment: We need way more context to be able to help you. What is your OCP setup etc

Comment: This is not about Openshift this is about Virtualization where i have a VM, i want to take a snapshot & make use of that snapshot to create a new VM in Openshift cluster.